# Batch-changing camera filenames to verbose filenames, one folder at a time

Tags: windows, powershell, batch

This is a question about Window PowerShell running on a desktop PC with Windows Home 64-bit.

I am changing about a hundred folders of photograph filenames from a camera and scanner like `005_2.JPG` to a verbose filename like `Some Kid Riding a Bicycle`.

I am using the Windows PowerShell command:

```
Dir | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("Some Kid Riding a Bicycle-{0}.jpg" -f $nr++)}
```

This runs fine.

But when I just CD\ to the next folder and just substitute a new string for the new subject in the new folder, the "index" number appended to the filename doesn't reset back to "1," but increments ahead to a higher number--not even the next number following the index in the previous operation (111 in this case).

If the last index in the last operation was "111" like this example:

```
-a----      2/4/2020   8:02 PM         404601 Some Kid Riding a Bicycle-111.jpg
```

and I then cd\ to a folder containing 8 files:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
-a----        1/16/2020  11:39 PM         598118 018_15.JPG

[6 lines omitted here]                                                          

-a----        1/16/2020  11:39 PM         727598 DSC017.jpg
```

and run:

```
> Dir | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("Some Old Guy Riding a Bicycle-{0}.jpg" -f $nr++)}
```

in that folder, the next filename in the output sequence is:

```
-a----   1/16/2020  11:39 PM     598118 Some Old Guy Riding a Bicycle-120.jpg
```

It looks like the index jumped ahead by the number of files in the new target folder. I'm wondering if those last few characters `-f $nr++`) are involved, but I haven't found any reference to a string like this in my meager library.

How do I fix this so it starts over with -1 (or some other preset value)?

Comment: Where is `$nr` comoing from?

Comment: `[ref]$i = 1; gci | Rename-Item -NewName {"Some Old Guy Riding a Bicycle-{0}.jpg" -f $i.Value++} -whatif` is one way. Using a scriptblock for `NewName` avoids ``ForEach` and keeps the pipeline flowing.

Comment: The entire | Rename-Item ... command is from: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-rename-multiple-files-bulk-windows-10#rename-files-using-powershell, which is just a "cookbook" that tells you to stir, but doesn't tell you how to stir or what stirring does. So to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$nr is your variable and you keep iterating its value with each command. It's scope is your PWSH session. as long as your session is open $nr value keeps increasing, unless you assign new value by issuing the instruction "$nr = 1".

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved. I was trying to modify the "$nr++" WITHIN the command and just sinking deeper into the swamp. Running the "$nr = 1" command AHEAD of the | Rename command is the answer. This is a great forum, but forgive me until I get used to this forum's software.

Comment: @NoGeneralities If this answer was helpful, please consider marking it as **accepted**. [See this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is **important**.